# Win8 migration HDD to SSD

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

Can you guys instruct me how to migrate a HDD to a SSD?

Also I was thinking about having ubuntu and win8 in the same SSD, 250GB each and then have the HDD for files only. I bought an MSI GT70 20C, do you guys recommend this idea of having both operative systems?

Comment: Not really I was also asking about a partion of ubuntu

Comment: Try to keep your questions to one question per question. ;)   Recommending whether you should or shouldn't dual boot to another OS isn't something we can answer, and would be off-topic as "opinion-based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try AOMEI Partition Assistant, you can clone the hdd to ssd using this program. hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks I'll definitely research more about AOMEI, what about having ubuntu installed on the same SSD?

Comment: Do you have ubuntu on the ssd, or do you want ubuntu and windows on it?

Comment: I want ubuntu and windows on it, Ubuntu for programming and win8 for all the games I've bought mostly, and then have both of the systems share the files from the HDD.

Comment: This is possible, Ubuntu actually has a wiki on this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

Use AOMEI as suggested. Only one tip, don't give 250GB partitions to each system. Ubuntu only needs 10 - 25 GB and windows only 80-150 GB. Use the rest for applications you need / want to run fast (read heavy games, browser,...).

Comment: Thank you!, In that case I will buy a 250 GB SSD and have a partition of 200 GB for win8 and games and only 50GB for Ubuntu which I will only be using for programming.

Comment: It will be better to have separate partition for windows and another for games. And if you only use ubuntu for programming, I suggest using even less. I have ubuntu in 10GB partition (containing root and home, don't have swap) and it only takes 6GB and runs without problem...