# Transfering Windows 10 from HDD to SSD

Tags: ssd

In short: how do I transfer a Windows 10 Home edition from an internal HDD to a newly installed M.2 SSD?

Notice that the new installation would NOT be in the same port. This is a laptop with two internal hard drives. The other answers are about replacing the drive into the same slot.

Details: given a Lenovo laptop with a 500 GB, 7200 RPM, 2,5", SATA3 and Windows 10 Home on it, I'd like to install a secondary internal 256GB, M.2 2280, NVMe, Opal 2.0 on it and run Windows 10 from it. There's also a Linux installation on the HDD but there's no real need to transfer this too and I believe it won't be a headache.

All the files in the HDD are less than 100GB.

Could I just boot into a Linux live CD and clone byte by byte the internal HDD into the SSD?

Does Windows have some official tool for that?

Comment: Most drives come with utilities to image across. Did yours? Also, there are a significant number of guides, and even questions here, about this. Have you looked those up and tried them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win8 migration HDD to SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/710741/win8-migration-hdd-to-ssd)

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=clone+windows+to+new+drive

Comment: All the major SSD manufacturers give you access to cloning software or you can use something like Macrium Reflect Free. Crucial guide is here https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLEvIPPJR6an86Tiner0ghBePVhUOv2pb

Comment: Even if cloned it I think you won't be able to boot because of hardware difference